# How to retrieve data from field with multiple="true" in AEM's WorkflowProcess?

Tags: dialog, adobe, workflow, aem, aem-6

Sorry if this is a basic question, as I am quite new to AEM.

I have a `cq dialog` allowing multiple tags to be entered.

```
<tags
cq:showOnCreate="{Boolean}true"
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="/libs/cq/gui/components/coral/common/form/tagfield"
allowCreate="{Boolean}true"
fieldLabel="Tags to add"
metaType="tags"
multiple="true" <====================
name="./metaData/TAGS"/>
```

[image]

I am trying to retrieve the two tags above in my WorkflowProcess as below:

```
@Component(
    //...
)
public class TagStep implements WorkflowProcess {
    @Override
    public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap processArguments) {
        try {
                //...
                List<String> tagslist = new ArrayList();
                List<String> tags = processArguments.get("TAGS",tagslist);

                // Nothing logged here <=======
                for (String tag: tags) {
                    LOG.info(tag);
                }

                //...
        } catch (Exception e){
            LOG.info("\n ERROR {} ",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

There is no output when I try to log `tag` in the loop above, probably the return type of `List<String>` cannot be converted.

What is the proper return type when using `multiple="true"`, and how to use `processArguments.get` to get the values?

Btw my code was based on the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1cV_xs2jGg&list=PLEaEQSM_Y4tk2o4YR7wptSIRFPKWNK60i&index=5).

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source implementation, it is using an Array, not a List. so here is how to retrieve the passed in data.

```
Node node = (Node) session.getItem(path);

String[] cars = {};
String[] tags = processArguments.get("TAGS",cars);

node.setProperty("cq:tags", tags);
```